# What happens if a modifier is not specified in java?

Tags: java, modifier

```
 class BTNode
 {    
     BTNode left, right;
     int data;

     //constructors and methods
}
```

In this piece of code no specific modifier is used. What happens then in context of modifier? are their any default behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Java docs:

> If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes)

[You can read about it here](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/09/default-access-modifier-in-java-or-no.html)